# How to target the first-child of an optgroup with css or jquery

Tags: jquery, css, optgroup

Is there a way to target the first-child of the optgroup labeled "Portfolio" displaying the name "Main"?

I need to remove it from showing only in a mobile menu (it doesn't display in the desktop menu). This is a Wordpress theme menu that is not accessible by Menus widget. The menu is created by a mobilemenu.js triggered by media query (I guess). It is displaying the Home page by 2 different names/menuitems. I was hoping to target just that menuitem and use a css display:none or a jQuery getElementByID solution but so far have had no luck. In a bit over my head on this one as I cannot seem to target it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<div class="mobilenavi">
  <select id="mm0" class="mnav" style="display: inline-block;">
    <option value="undefined">Click here:</option>
    <option value="http://somedomain.com/">Home</option>
    <optgroup label="Portfolios">
      <option value="#">Main</option>
      <option value="http://somedomain.com/portfolio-1/">Portfolio 1</option>
      <option value="http://somedomain.com/portfolios/portfolio-2/">Portfolio 2</option>
      <option value="http://somedomain.com/portfolios/portfolio-3/">Portfolio 3</option>
      <option value="http://somedomain.com/portfolios/beach-portfolio/">Beach Portfolio</option>
      <option value="http://somedomain.com/portfolios/photos/">Photos</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="http://somedomain.com/contact/">Contact Kim</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This CSS approach would work in some browsers:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZKMT/)

```
optgroup[label="Portfolios"] option:first-child {
    display:none;
}
```

---

As @canon points out, `display:none` won't work in all browsers though.

If you want to remove it with jQuery, use:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VEG4c/)

```
$('optgroup[label="Portfolios"] option:first-child').remove();
```

Alternatively, if you want a pure JS approach:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/39P2m/)

```
var el = document.querySelector('optgroup[label="Portfolios"]');
el.removeChild(el.getElementsByTagName('option')[0]);
```

Comment: +1 for the selector... but `display:none` for `<option>` isn't universally compliant.

Comment: Josh Crozier, thank you for the thorough, multi-approach answer.

Nothing has worked for me yet. CSS works in desktop browser when resized to trigger media query for mobile sizes but not Android Chrome browser.

Have tried adding both jquery/js solutions in both footer and header, before the wp_head/wp_footer theme hooks with no luck.

I thought js/jquery would work in footer with $(function() {//code}); but no luck there. Obviously I'm early in my jquery learning curve.

I do think your answers will work in a normal theme though and will mark as the solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Does $('optgroup option:nth-child(1)').hide(); work?